# sql server 2008 R2 reporting services subscriptions options

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting

I am trying to set up email delivery for some reports. Just finished some sample reports and uploaded to the report server. Now the online documentation talks about creating subscriptions and the best way to do this is click on the drop down menu as you hover over a report. I have seen this before a long time ago when I worked on this but for some reason I don't see that option. I don't have any menu options for either report. I can see the My Subscriptions option of the top right but nothing is in there.

[image]

Appreciate any ideas?

EDIT

Used the debugger and  found this:

SCRIPT5007:

```
Unable to set property 'className' of undefined or null reference 
ReportingServices.js, line 1298 character 24
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing something is stopping the DHTML from running.

Add your report server to IE's Trusted Sites list.

Comment: Also add the report server to IE's compatibility list (something I should have added to my original post, sorry). This could also be tested by finding a machine with IE9 on it and seeing if everything works from there. If so, maybe uninstall IE11 or IE10?

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix after hours of searching:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/20835df1-9c6b-479b-9d78-15437fdb78cb/reportserver-manager-script-error?forum=sqlreportingservices

who would have thought it was some javascript issue.